# USB not booting and BIOS correctly set

Tags: boot, usb, bios

I'm trying to boot an old notebook ([Toshiba Satellite 1135-S1553](https://support.toshiba.com/support/modelHome?freeText=434998)) from USB but so far it didn't work. I have already tried several different ways:

- All 3 USB ports.
- Different USB devices. (USB flash drives and external hard disk drive)
- Different ISO files. (Debian, Peppermint, Tiny Core, etc…)

I'm sure the USB devices + iso were bootable since [GNOME Disks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Disks) showed 'bootable partition' and they all booted on more recent machines.
And I'm pretty sure that the BIOS configuration is properly set:

- Legacy USB support enabled.
- USB device properly shown at the BIOS screen. (ex: Generic USB Flash Disk, ScanDisk or Mass Storage Device)
- Boot order set to begin with removable devices.

Why this machine is not booting from USB? Is it possible that the USB is available at the BIOS boot menu, but actually the hardware does not handle it? How can I be sure that this machine can or can not boot from USB?

Comment: There may be an additional keypress needed during boot to force the choice to USB... try holding F11 or F8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% familiar with booting from a USB flash drive on—what is essentially—a Windows PC like this since I am a Mac person. But [this site](https://nmilosev.svbtle.com/booting-uefi-usb-stick-on-a-toshiba-laptop-insydeh20-bios) seems to have some good info:

> If you have InsydeH2O bios, you may have some trouble booting from UEFI flash drive (with linux or Win8 or higher).
>
> There is a ton of advice, like to switch to CSM boot mode, but that defeats the point of UEFI. So some tips for you:

The core steps are as follows:

> To boot this drive after many hours of trying, sadly only because of a bug:
>
> - **Reset your bios to default settings!**
> - Leave Secureboot ON
> - Turn Fastboot OFF
> - Save settings with F10
> - Hold <kbd>F12</kbd> while booting to get to the boot menu, and select your USB.
> - It should boot!

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm not sure why it worked, but after resetting the BIOS to default settings, suddenly the USB device (ex: Generic USB Flash Disk) appeared in the hard drive section (very weird place to appear by the way) of the boot menu.

Comment: Not wierd at all. It is a solid state drive after all ;). I'm glad you got it working.  Are those isos UEFI boot? If so resetting the bios might have undone the legacy mode, and that could be why it worked.

Comment: @GuyGastineau > _"Not wierd at all. It is a solid state drive after all ;)."_ If so, I'm wondering why the "removable device" section.

Answer (score 0):

Didn’t work for my Insydeh2o rev 5.0 bios. The config tab shows the new blank SSD but when I Save and Exit no device ever shows up on the window that says choose a device option or insert recovery media then enter. Boot Manager window always comes up with no devices showing

Comment: Also, did try using recovery media but same result. Even though USB is enabled neither of the two will work. Both USB ports are working on the HDD. I am just trying to upgrade to an SSD!

Comment: BRW, My system is Ideapad 110-15IBR   MTM 80T7

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1150951)